How do I merge the results of both queries into one based on one field in Splunk?
I have below query that returns fields "RequestId,responseBody, Time, responseCode,requestBody"
index=docee_logs sourcetype="kube:container:xyz" 
    [ search index=docee_logs host=sl***** source="/var/log/containers/**.log" sourcetype="kube:container:*xyz*" "callType\\\":[\\\"12\\\"" AND  "Activity"  AND "Time=" 
    | rex field=_raw "Time=(?<proctime>.*), apiVersion" 
    | where proctime > 3000 
    | eval RequestId=replace(RequestId, "\\\\'", "")
    | fields RequestId 
    | rename RequestId as search 
    | format] 
| search "Activity" AND requestUrl="\\'/Request\\'"
| eval RequestId=replace(RequestId, "\\\\'", "")
| eval requestBody=replace(requestBody, "\\\\'", "") 
| eval requestBody=replace(requestBody, "\\\\", "")
| table RequestId,responseBody, Time, responseCode,requestBody

There is another query that results "request_url" including common field as RequestId
index=docee_logs sourcetype="kube:container:xyz" 
    [ search index=docee_logs host=sl******* source="/var/log/containers/**.log" sourcetype="kube:container:*xyz*" "callType\\\":[\\\"12\\\"" AND  "Activity"  AND "Time=" 
    | rex field=_raw "Time=(?<proctime>.*), apiVersion" 
    | where proctime > 3000 
    | eval RequestId=replace(RequestId, "\\\\'", "")
    | fields RequestId 
    | rename RequestId as search 
    | format]
| search "Sending merchant notification, Url" 
| rex "Sending merchant notification, Url=(?P<request_url>[^,]*)"
| table request_url,vrolRequestId

I am doing below but it is not returning results from first query. Can someone please help?
index=docee_logs sourcetype="kube:container:xyz" 
    [ search "Activity" AND requestUrl="\\'/Request\\'" index=docee_logs
        [ search index=docee_logs host=sl***** source="/var/log/containers/**.log" sourcetype="kube:container:*xyz*" "callType\\\":[\\\"12\\\"" AND  "Activity"  AND "Time=" 
        | rex field=_raw "Time=(?<proctime>.*), apiVersion" 
        | where proctime > 3000 
        | eval RequestId=replace(RequestId, "\\\\'", "")
        | fields RequestId 
        | rename RequestId as search 
        | format
        ]
] | append [ search "Sending merchant notification, Url" index=docee_logs
        [ search index=docee_logs host=sl****** source="/var/log/containers/**.log" sourcetype="kube:container:*xyz*" "callType\\\":[\\\"12\\\"" AND  "Activity"  AND "Time=" 
        | rex field=_raw "Time=(?<proctime>.*), apiVersion" 
        | where proctime > 3000 
        | eval RequestId=replace(RequestId, "\\\\'", "")
        | fields RequestId 
        | rename RequestId as search 
        | format
        ]
] 
| rex "Sending merchant notification, Url=(?P<request_url>[^,]*)" 
| table RequestId,responseBody, Time, responseCode, requestBody,request_url


There are a few ways to combine two queries.  The simplest is to use the append command to run them both then regroup the results using stats.
<<search 1>>
| append [ <<search 2>> ]
| stats values(*) as * by <<some field(s) common to both searches>>

It may be necessary to rename fields in one of the searches to achieve common field names.
<<search 1>>
| append [ <<search 2>> | rename <<some field>> as <<some field from search 1>> ]
| stats values(*) as * by <<some field(s) common to both searches>>

The better method is to refactor the searches into a single search that does the same thing as the two original searches.  It looks like you tried a combination of these two approaches.
Refactoring is easier when the two searches search the same data as is the case here.
Start with the common bits
index=docee_logs sourcetype="kube:container:xyz" 
    [ search index=docee_logs host=sl***** source="/var/log/containers/**.log" sourcetype="kube:container:*xyz*" "callType\\\":[\\\"12\\\"" AND  "Activity"  AND "Time=" 
    | rex field=_raw "Time=(?<proctime>.*), apiVersion" 
    | where proctime > 3000 
    | eval RequestId=replace(RequestId, "\\\\'", "")
    | fields RequestId 
    | rename RequestId as search 
    | format] 

The two search commands can be combined using OR before the first pipe.
("Activity" AND requestUrl="\\'/Request\\'") OR ("Sending merchant notification, Url")

The eval and rex commands come next.
| eval RequestId=replace(RequestId, "\\\\'", "")
| eval requestBody=replace(requestBody, "\\\\'", "") 
| eval requestBody=replace(requestBody, "\\\\", "")
| rex "Sending merchant notification, Url=(?P<request_url>[^,]*)"

That leaves us with two table commands, which we can merge into one.
| table RequestId responseBody Time responseCode requestBody request_url vrolRequestId

For a final query that looks like this:
index=docee_logs sourcetype="kube:container:xyz" 
    [ search index=docee_logs host=sl***** source="/var/log/containers/**.log" sourcetype="kube:container:*xyz*" "callType\\\":[\\\"12\\\"" AND  "Activity"  AND "Time=" 
    | rex field=_raw "Time=(?<proctime>.*), apiVersion" 
    | where proctime > 3000 
    | eval RequestId=replace(RequestId, "\\\\'", "")
    | fields RequestId 
    | rename RequestId as search 
    | format] 
    ("Activity" AND requestUrl="\\'/Request\\'") OR ("Sending merchant notification, Url")
| eval RequestId=replace(RequestId, "\\\\'", "")
| eval requestBody=replace(requestBody, "\\\\'", "") 
| eval requestBody=replace(requestBody, "\\\\", "")
| rex "Sending merchant notification, Url=(?P<request_url>[^,]*)"
| table RequestId responseBody Time responseCode requestBody request_url vrolRequestId

This may be imperfect since I'm not aware of the magic that created the 'volRequestId' field.  Also, some regrouping of the results may still be needed, using the stats command as above.
